# How to delete all comments in a selected code section?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, macros, keyboard-shortcuts

Every once in a while, my code gets littered with many useless comments, most of them are obsolete lines of code, and some are obsolete "memos to self".
So I was wondering if there's a way to just select a code section, and with some magic key combination or macro, delete all of those.

Thanks.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

For searching and replacing code in Visual Studio - Visual Studio has a built in find and replace. [Use regular expressions in Visual Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/using-regular-expressions-in-visual-studio)

The below regular expression will also remove spaces before the comments too.

```
(\t+|\s+|\r\n)((/\*([^*]|[\r\n]|(\*+([^*/]|[\r\n])))*\*+/)|(//.*))
```

[http://blog.ostermiller.org/find-comment](http://web.archive.org/web/20170909055410/http://blog.ostermiller.org/find-comment)

Comment: since "/\\*.*\\*/" didn't find multiline comments this saved my day. Thanks

Answer (score 19):

Open the Document, Hit Ctrl+H or locate and Open "Quick Replace"

1 Enable Regular Expression (Alt+E) 
2 In Find FieldBox, write

> **//.*** or **/*.***

3 In Replace FieldBox, keep it empty or put text of your choice. 
Note: /* */ - Multilines Comment Deletion has limitaton

Comment: For those having trouble - escape the asterisks and go ahead and match the final slash, i.e. `/\*.*\*/`

Answer (score 9):

1.`//.*?\n`
2.`/\*(.|\n)*?\*/`
These RE will also delete multi-line comments. (Just use find and replace with Regular Expression turned on).

Comment: The first regex broke also web links.

Answer (score 6):

I believe the search & replace in VS allows for regular expressions, it would be easy enough to search for "// (anything to end of line" or "/* (anything) */" and replace with "".

Since this is c++ (I think), one could write the regex so that it would not find 'escaped' comments.

Comment: But it does not allow for doing the find / replace for a selection of code in between lots of other code :(

Comment: Oops. I was wrong. In the "Look in:" combodropdown there's an option called "Selection"... :) Yippie

Comment: Can you provide examples of such expressions please?

Comment: @dumbledad - since this is c++ (I think), one could write the regex so that it would not find 'escaped' comments. Anyway, I would assumed the author would review each search/replace and not just do them all unchecked!

Comment: Good call, I was assuming it would be done without checking! If you edit your answer to include that I can cancel my -1

Comment: Keep in mind that this regex is also true for URLs like https ://stackoverflow.com

Comment: @besserwisser, you might be able to use a negative lookbehind (?<!) to exclude those from the search. No problem is too great or too small for regex!

Comment: I agree, but I think the answer should be improved to mitigate this problem.

Comment: I was relieved to see @jonmeyer actually provided a regex in his answer so I didn't have to put one here. Maybe I'll try to get him to update his answer. I hate writing those things!

Answer (score 3):

I would like to combine the two answers and write my own answer.

1. Open the Document, Hit **Ctrl+H** or locate and Open "Quick Replace" ([See Arpan's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14895648/8810311) )
2. Hit  **Alt+E** for enable Regular Expression
3. In Find FieldBox, write the following regular expression ([See Jonmeyer's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42962814/8810311))

   `(\t+|\s+|\r\n)((/\*([^*]|[\r\n]|(\*+([^*/]|[\r\n])))*\*+/)|(//.*))`
4. In Replace FieldBox, keep it **empty** or put text of your choice.

For example:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

you can also use [this](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=MadsKristensen.CommentRemover) visual studio extension for removing comments in your code. 
just see that link and you will find description for how to remove comments.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't specify a language in your question.  Above answers will work for c#.

For Visual Basic, a search for the regex `'.*$` and replace with nothing will remove all comments.

Answer (score 0):

/ \ * . * \ * /  use this to find long comment lines. (delete spaces.)

you can also look [here](http://blog.ostermiller.org/find-comment)

Answer (score 0):

Only one-line comments also remove spaces before and new lines if a comment is the only text in line.

```
(^ *//.*\r\n)|(//.*)
```

Answer (score 0):

This could be accomplished by utilizing "**Find and Replace**" or "**Quick Replace**".

To begin, enable **Regular Expressions** and type `^\s*\/\/.*\n` into the search box, leaving the Replace field empty. Then, click the "**Replace All**" button.

In order to remove comments from the end of lines as well, you can adapt the preceding pattern to look like this:

```
(\n^)*\s*\/\/.*
```